# Expand/Collapse part of code in jsp using Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, foreach, expand

I've to display a table only on click of the + (Expand) and + should get changed to - and I should collapse the table once - is clicked. I've the below code in the jsp page:

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${clientFilterList}" varStatus="status">

<tr  class="${status.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
    <td width = "5" valign="middle" align = "left">
    <img id=MYFEE<c:out value = "${status.index}"/> class="SectionImage" name = "IMGMYFEE<c:out value = "${status.index}"/>"
             align="right" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/explorerOpen.gif"  
             onclick="collapseSection('MYFEE<c:out value = "${status.index}"/>', 'MYFEE',event);"/></td>

    <td>${type.key}</td>
    <td>${type.value}</td>

   <c:set var="type" value=${type}></c:set>
   <c:set var = "ifeeCount" value = "${status.index}" scope = "request"/>
   <c:set var = "typeCollapse" value = "MYFEE" scope = "request"/>
   <c:set var = "editableVal" value = "editable${ifeeCount}" scope = "request"/>
```

And my javascript method is as below:

```
function collapseSection(collapseArea, areaType,event){
var collapseImage = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/explorerClose.gif';
var expandImage = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/explorerOpen.gif';
var noOfRows = 0;

if (areaType == 'MYFEE')
{
    noOfRows = document.getElementById('noOfclients').value;
}

sectionCollapse(collapseImage, expandImage, collapseArea, noOfRows, areaType,event);
     }

function sectionCollapse(collapseImg, expandImg, collapseArea, noOfRows,   areaType,event)
   {
    elementToColapse = document.getElementById(collapseArea);
    var event = event || window.event;

    var imageElem = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;


    while (elem.tagName != 'TABLE' ){ 
        elem = elem.parentElement;
    } 

    elementToColapse.style.display = 'none';
    //Now see if we need to expand of callapse

    if (elementToColapse.style.display=='none') {
        for (i = 0; i <= noOfRows; i++)
        {
            otherElement = document.getElementById(areaType + i);
            if (otherElement.style.display != 'none')
            {
                document.getElementById('IMG' + areaType + i).src = expandImg;
                otherElement.style.display= 'none'; 
            }
        }

        imageElem.src = collapseImg;
        elementToColapse.style.display= ''; 
        elem.className = 'sectionTitleOpen';
    } else {
        imageElem.src = expandImg;
        elementToColapse.style.display= 'none'; 
        elem.className = 'sectionTitleClosed';
    }
 }
```

When I click on '+' It just disappears and the expand doesn't work. Could you tell me what's missing?Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @BalusC ,  can someone help me with the issue?

Comment: @Razz can someone help me with the issue?

Comment: I dont use java / jsp, so that content makes it hard for me to read. As your question is really just a javascript/html question, you would probably get more help if you show only the generated html (rather than serverside jsp)